# text and image views loading separately in grid view of android

Tags: java, android, gridview

How can we create a grid view which contains both images and text views in its cells separately. Like, a grid having 12 items, in which there are 6 imageviews and rest 6 are textviews. The position of image and text should be dynamic. Also how can I load the images and text respectively from server?

I had gone through various post, but did not help me with this type of scenario. Your help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you check `RecyclerView`?

Comment: I did check, but couldn't find exactly. Could you please provide some logic for this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use a table. You may not have known this was an option. Similar to a gridView but you can customise the contents however you want.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/grid.html